# Tableau - Data Source Connection Information of Published Data sources

Tags: tableau-api

I have a twb file which uses a published data source. I want to check the connection details of the data source. The twb file gives me only the published data source(tableau server details) details. The rest API to get data source connection details gives only the server details of the local data source. All other information like DB, schema and table information are missing.
If I have a twb connecting directly to my local data sources, the XML has all the connection information including server, schema, DB and table names.
How do I check the DB, schema and tables the twb file is using when it uses a published data source?

Thanks

Comment: Download the tds from the server. It's XML and you can parse through and get the details.

Comment: Check out [Power Tools for Tableau Desktop](http://powertoolsfortableau.com/get-better-insight-data-source-audit) from Interworks. There is a data source auditing feature that will do the heavy lifting of parsing things out for you from the XML both in the twb file and the published data source. Disclaimer: I do not work for Interworks but I am a very satisfied customer and use Power Tools for data source auditing.

Comment: Hi sam, The data source is in tdsx format. I tried renaming it to tds. Did not help.

Comment: Renaming it won't work. Open the tdxs file in Desktop. Right click on the connection name and choose Add to Saved Data Sources. This will save it as a tds. You can then open and parse the tds in your favorite editor.

Comment: Another option is to use tabcmd and do a GET to the datasource. See https://community.tableau.com/thread/177940

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sam. Looks like the tds file also points to the tableau server published data source. I need information about the local data sources i.e., underlying connection details of the published data sources.

I tried the postgresSQL. I still do not have the schema information :(